# Python - how to get executable program to get the windows file browser to pop up for user to choose an excel file or any other document?

Tags: python, excel, file, exe, explorer

The program would follow the below steps:

1. Click on executable program made through python
2. File explorer pops up for user to choose excel file to alter
3. Choose excel file for executable program to alter
4. Spits out txt file OR excel spreadsheet with newly altered data to same folder location as the original spreadsheet

Comment: Windows Explorer isn't made for selecting files; that's what file open dialogs are for. You're going to need some kind of GUI library.

Comment: Hi @Rawing, I was referring to a pop up such as the following image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/images/picker-multifile-600px.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is perfectly doable. I suggest you look at PyQT5 or TkInter for the user interface, pyexcel for the excel interface and pyinstaller for packaging up an executable as you asked. There are many great tutorials on all of these modules.

Comment: Thank you @StuartBuckingham. Firstly, I've just begun self-learning Python and have many questions, apologies in advance if they may seem very basic haha. In regards to PyQT5 and TkInter, I have looked into both packages and they definitely have to do with the UI but there doesn't seem to be a feature where I am prompted to search through my windows explorer to identify the excel spreadsheet I require. For example, it would look like the following image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/images/picker-multifile-600px.png.

Comment: Here's a full tutorial on file dialogs. https://pythonspot.com/en/pyqt5-file-dialog/ Please try searching for this material instead.

Comment: Thanks @StuartBuckingham. TkInter script I came across has helped tremendously. Appreciate the answers of course. What a collaborative community. I will continue to search for more material instead.

Comment: Good luck @Ajo. If my answer helped, click the green tick and upvote the answer please.